# In R, how to create a schedule of tasks within their required window that maximizes a given resource utilization (i.e. project teams)

Tags: r

I have a list of a week's worth of tasks (about 2,000) that need to be done within a given timeframe ordered by how many minutes the task can be moved.  Each task takes 1 hour.  Table name is Task_List.  We have 5 teams that can perform 1 taks at a time, so 5 different tasks can be ongoing.

| Task | Earliest_Start_Task | Latest_Start_Task | Window |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-07 07:35:00 | 2022-09-07 07:35:00 | 0 |
| 2 | 2022-09-07 08:00:00 | 2022-09-07 08:00:00 | 0 |
| 3 | 2022-09-07 17:43:00 | 2022-09-07 17:49:00 | 6 |
| 4 | 2022-09-07 09:49:00 | 2022-09-07 10:00:00 | 11 |

I am trying to determine a schedule for the optimal start times for these tasks given the following constraints:

1. The tasks must be started by the Latest_Start_Task time for each task
2. Avoid going over the maximum of 5 at one time during the 1 hour duration of each task.  It will be inevitable, but I want to minimize these occurrences as much as possible.  Ideally, the times where the task count goes over the threshold of 5, I would like to identify which task is causing the overtime and when.

Comment: Please see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This question is not reproducible - it is not really a coding question - so I am voting to close. You might want to look at packages like [criticalpath](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/criticalpath/vignettes/criticalpath-introduction.html). Once you have written some code to attempt to solve the problem, feel free to make the question a bit more focused, or ask another.

Comment: ^ agree this question isn't reproducible, and not clearly defined enough to answer as is. You might look at the `IpSolve` package and search for "linear optimization."